# Is the font size different for each mobile phone(iPhone)?

Tags: swift, iphone, pixel, font-size, point

Is the font size different for each mobile phone?

```
example)

fontSize = 24
iPhone 11 pro -> 24
iPhone SE -> 20
```

Since the resolution is different for each mobile phone, does the font size change?

Comment: The font size of what!?

Comment: Label, UITextField etc!!

Comment: All I can say is that you don't change the font size of a UILabel object or whatever conditional to the device model.

Comment: Regardless of all resolutions, if the size is 24, are all models the same size?